# com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: for firebase login

Tags: android, firebase

I am facing Google login issue. It was working before but I had stop sometime the google login. I had delete SHA-1 key and stop also from firebase authenticator system. But I have opened the system and add SHA-1 key. Delete the google-service.json add the new google-service.json but it is not working. config the signConfigs.

It show `com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10:`

What I can do now?